# WordPress can't access widget in footer with Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm trying to access a widget in my footer, but am getting an output of 0. I've registered the widget as a sidebar:

```
register_sidebar( array(
  'name' => __( 'First Footer Widget Area', 'bonestheme' ),
  'id' => 'first-footer-widget-area',
  'description' => __( 'The first footer widget area', 'bonestheme' ),
  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => '</div>',
  'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
  'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

My footer.php looks like this:

```
$timberContext = $GLOBALS['timberContext'];
if (!isset($timberContext)) {
  throw new \Exception('Timber context not set in footer.');
}
$timberContext['content'] = ob_get_contents();
$timberContext['first-footer-widget'] = Timber::get_widgets('first-footer-widget-area');
ob_end_clean();
$templates = array('page-plugin.twig');
Timber::render($templates, $timberContext);
```

In my footer.twig I try to access the widget like this:

```
{{ first-footer-widget }}
```

I have two text fields in my widget, titled label and value. I've tried {{ first-footer-widget.label }} and {{ first-footer-widget.value }} to no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This one's pretty easy, Twig doesn't-like-hyphens. Just rename the property and how you're fetching it to be `first_footer_widget`

Comment: This seems right. Also you can call {{ dump() }} or {{ dump(VALUEHERE) }} to examine if you are even getting the data you expect.